# Can't I use functions inside other functions in R?

Tags: r

I've been having trouble understanding functions and environments, so I tried writing a simple function to simplify the problem. I wrote the following code:

```
h <- c(1:5)
meta <- function(){
  resta <- function(){
    v <- h-2
    assign("h", v, envir = globalenv())
    h
  }
}
```

Now, when I call `resta()`, it takes `2` from `h`, shows me the result and changes its value in the global environment, but if I call `meta()` nothing at all happens, `h` doesn't change its value in the global environment.

I also tried the `resta` function by itself (not inside another function) and it works just fine.

Am I missing something? Is R not able to run functions like this? is there any explanation for this related to environments?

Comment: This may help: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html

Comment: `resta()` is not called from anywhere. Right after its definition, in the body of `meta()` write `resta()`. This will be the last instruction of `meta()` and therefore its return value.

Comment: Two notes: 1) `c(1:5)` and `1:5` are the same object. 2) You are using `h` inside `meta()` without passing it as a formal argument. This is legal but bad practice. If you use variables in a function get the habit of passing them to the functions or to create them in the functions. Like this your code will have self contained functions, with less side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to get your `meta` function worked:

```
h <- c(1:5)

meta <- function(){
  resta <- function(){
    v <- h-2
    h <<- v
    v
  }
  resta()
}
```

You need to call `resta()` inside `meta` at the end to make it as a return value.

Also, instead of `assign("h", v, envir = globalenv())`, you can use superassignment `<<-` which assigns h in the environment of `meta` if one exists there before going to search in an environment above -- in this case it goes to the global environment, *i.e.*

**Hadley Wickham**: "`<<-` never creates a variable in the current environment, but instead modifies an existing variable found in a parent environment.
If <<- doesn’t find an existing variable, it will create one in the global environment." (**Chapter 7: Environments, Advanced R**)

Check that `meta()` and `h` evaluate to the same value:

Calling once:

```
meta()
h

> meta()
[1] -1  0  1  2  3
> h
[1] -1  0  1  2  3
>
```

Calling the second time:

```
meta()
h

> meta()
[1] -3 -2 -1  0  1
> h
[1] -3 -2 -1  0  1
>
```

And so on...

Comment: "*<<- which assigns h into the gloab (global) env.*" - be careful here. It may well assign to `h` in the environment of `meta` if one exists there before it goes searching in the global environment. Or for that matter, the environment of a function that calls `meta`, or a function that calls that function etc....

Comment: @thelatemail, very good catch, thanks. I will edit the answer with your comment.

Comment: ohhhhhh of course, it didn't work because I was just defining the function, but not aplying it! many many thanks fam

Comment: @thelatemail:  No, it would never install in "the environment of a function that calls `meta`, etc."  Callers are irrelevant, only the environment chain matters.  The first two sentences of your comment are correct.

Comment: @user2554330 - good point, I am indeed wrong on the last half. Could you propose an edit to the answer?

Comment: Thanks, @user2554330, just modified the answer.